# JSON encoding an associative array containing quotes

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an associative array:

```
$contents = array();
$contents["notes"] = "this doesn't seem like it will work";
```

(For sake of simplicity, the above string is not actually defined in-line in my code, it is fetched from the MySQL DB)

When I do:

```
 echo json_encode($contents, JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

It fails silently and I don't see any output sent to javascript.

However, if the array `$contents` is not associative, `JSON_HEX_APOS` seems to convert the quotes as it should, and `json_encode` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Your code works fine. You can drop those three lines into http://phptester.net/ and it'll spit out the JSON as you'd expect. @pol was correct with his answer -- your original question contained code where the array was not instantiated correctly.

Comment: I edited my question slightly to say that the string is not defined in-line in my code, it is fetched from a MySQL database. Perhaps, that's why this error couldn't be exactly reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a valid PHP array definition. Try instead,

- With PHP <5.4: `$contents = array("notes => "it'll work!")`
- With PHP >=5.4: same as above or `$contents = ["notes" => "yey"]`

And then your echo should work.

--EDIT
As per your edit, the array looks good now. If that's not the problem, check encoding errors with `echo json_last_error()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I edited my question. I now state exactly how I have defined it.

Comment: I tried `echo son_last_error()` and I get `5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8`, any ideas? Doing `utf8_encode()` to the string fixes the JSON, but the single quotes from the string disappears. Perhaps, it is worth mentioning, the string containing single-quotes is fetched from a database and not defined in-line as in my question.

Comment: check out your db encoding and use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Answer (score 1):

Json_encode usually take array as a parameter.
Your code is almost fine.
Just tweak it a bit like this

$contents = array();
$contents["notes"] = "this doesn't seem like it will work";

echo json_encode(array("data"=>$contents), JSON_HEX_APOS);